# How do I write a custom attribute for const fields in my Rust library?

Tags: rust, precompile, rust-proc-macros

I'd like to write a custom attribute for a `const` field, which will later be accessed throughout my entire library.

**Example**

```rs
// default declaration in `my_lib`...
pub const INITIAL_VEC_CAPACITY: usize = 10;
```

```rs
//...but can be overriden by dependent crates...
#[mylib_initial_vec_capacity]
pub const INITIAL_VEC_CAPACITY: usize = 5;
```

```rs
//...then can be accessed within my crate:
pub fn do_something() {
    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(macros::INITIAL_VEC_CAPACITY);
    /* do stuff with vec */
}
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Why do you need an attribute for that, just `const` works great.

Comment: > which will later be accessed throughout my entire library.

Comment: > //...but can be overriden by dependent crates...

Comment: I don't understand? I asked a clear question, and I want an answer for my question. What if others were to see my post, and search for an answer that not only answers mine, but others' question(s)?

Comment: Oops, I had typos :E I meant "What **if** two **crates** create incompatible values?"

Comment: Whatever Rust chooses. You don't experience that issue because Rust supposedly handles all of that.

Comment: What do you mean "whatever Rust chooses"? It should be random?

Comment: I'd assume that Rust would choose whichever is creating the binary..?

Comment: No, if both are in the dependencies.

Comment: I just want an answer. I'll deal with all of that later.

Comment: Here's an answer: there's nothing like that in Rust. Is it enough for you?

Comment: If you want to provide an answer, it's probably best to provide a formal, well-written one, using the "Answer Question" button below so others can find it more easily.

Comment: But I don't want to post that as an answer, because it probably isn't useful. If you will elaborate more on your problem, or at least answer my questions, then I may be able to help you (and others), or at least provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `features` to allow the user the compilation process of your library.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features-examples.html

Other than that I think you should use some configuration object the user passes into your code or is able to configure from outside using one of the following crates

- https://crates.io/crates/config
- https://crates.io/crates/config-derive/0.1.6
- https://crates.io/crates/envconfig